# SImple macro to delete all unused columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have linked a spreadsheet to a database and have created a macro that clears the contents of the worksheet and pastes In the results of the SQL I send to the database.

It returns about 30 columns of data with about 6000 rows of data, yet the file size ballooned to 22mb!? I read on here about deleting/hiding empty columns and cells and this reduced the file to 2.5mb.

Is there a quick macro that will save me having to do this manually each day please? I've seen a lot of variants on Google and I can't get one to work correctly.

The number of columns stays the same each day but the number of rows fluctuate.

Comment: I've cut it down to the minimum, removed DB names and password and any identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub hide_Empty_Columns()
Dim lastCol&, i&
Dim dataCol$

lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = lastCol To 1 Step -1
    With Columns(i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i)) = 0 Then
            Columns(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Pretty straightforward. You can tweak as needed.  It hides any column that is completely empty.  If you want instead to delete the column, change the `Columns(i).Hidden` line to `Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that now. Do I put this at the end of my code?

Comment: @HeyVBA - I don't know what your code looks like, so I'm not sure.  You could just call this from when you need to. (Post your code in your OP if you want me to see if I can tell where to add it).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I too have had this problem in the past. Mostly the macros to delete unused columns and rows didn't help much. (some but not much).

I found that most of the problem was 2 things.
1) Excel saving a bunch of XML history.
2. Cluttered VBA.

Try these two things. 
1)Save your file as an xlsb file. This will change everything to binary and save wasted xml space.
2)use code cleaner utility found here http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm It's amazing how much space that thing can save for you.

BTW, if you save your file as a myfile.zip you can open it up and see where the bulk of your issue is. Be-careful about editing there because you may corrupt things.

Hope this helps.